# PhantomJS spawns many child processes

Tags: python, selenium, memory, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm starting PhantomJS (v2.1.1) with Selenium (v2.53.1) in my `python` code. Newly created process spawns 19-20 child PhantomJS processes right after start.

Here comes what I did:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> dcap = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS.copy()
>>> dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = "Some UA string"     
>>> b = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
>>> b.service.process.pid
28304
```

After that I checked all the children of `28304` with `pstree` and saw:

```
> sudo pstree -p 28304
phantomjs(28304)─┬─{phantomjs}(28305)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28306)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28307)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28308)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28309)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28310)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28311)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28312)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28313)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28314)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28315)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28336)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28337)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28338)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28339)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28340)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28341)
                 ├─{phantomjs}(28342)
                 └─{phantomjs}(28343)
```

Is this an issue? How can I decrease the number of children to decrease memory usage?